# Listener port XXXXXXXX could not be started in WebSphere Application Server 7

Tags: websphere, listener, websphere-7

**Error:**

```
Listener port SonicLogQCF.CIILog could not be started.
```

**Missing Tab** (Runtime)

When i noticed with other working Application Server listener ports, i can see two tabs one with title **Configuration** and one with title **Runtime**. ( As shown below )

[image]

However in not working listener port i can only see one tab with title **Configuration**

[image]

### -

### -

### -

-

**Adding more Details** ( as per Manglu ):

I have a weird situation for example

1. Application named "ABC" *has* Runtime tab for Logs and Trace, but *no* Runtime tab for listening port for the same Application - **NOT WORKING**
2. Application named "XYZ" has *no* Runtime tab for both logs and trace and listening port - **NOT WORKING**
3. Application named "QWE" *has* Runtime tab for both logs and trace and listening port - **WORKING**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally able to fix the problem but don't have answer for root cause.

```
Application servers > "Application"
```

Configurations (this is tab)

[image]

**unchecked** "Start component as needed" as shown below

[image]

```
Apply --> Ok ---> Save
```

restart the server and you should see all listener ports **RUNNING**

Comment: This sounds interesting!!. Start Components as needed is simply a flag which controls when components are started. if this is turned off,all the WAS components are started up at start server time (making the start time longer). If it is turned off and the run-time notices it needs it, it would start on demand when it is required to. For production machines, i would never do this. As a side comment, I would also not "allow" access to internal server classes.

Answer (score 1):

Missing Runtime tab typically implies that the server is **not running** or the **Dmgr is unable to get hold of the server** (via the SOAP or RMI internal communication calls).

Is the runtime tab available in the other parts of the console (for example trace section)?

Comment: i have added more details in question, let me know your thoughts